# Recreate SPL Transfer from a `CompiledInstruction`

Tags: web3.js, spl-token

i wanted to ask if i can decode an existing SPL token transfer from transaction hash only.

`const transaction = await client.getTransaction(transactionHash!);`

Returns a `TransactionReponse` from `@solana/web3.js` which contains `CompiledInstructions`. Id be really interested to know if it's possible to recreate a `TransferInstruction` from existing on chain data

Answer (score 0):

Certainly! Pass in the `jsonParsed` encoding when fetching the transaction, and it will try to decode any SPL token instructions.

You can find out more information about `jsonParsed` encoding at https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#parsed-responses